# Why does MySQL say 'Unsupported operand types' when checking for existence of a date in my query?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have the following code and I want to take the timestamp stored in `$begin` and pass it to a MySQL query, but the query is failing with:

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types
```

Here's the code used to populate the variable `$begin`:

```
$datepicker_begin = "01/07/2013";
$begin = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $datepicker_begin);
$beginObj = $begin->format('Y-m-d');
$begin = strtotime($beginObj);  // becomes Unix Timestamp
```

Here is the code for the query. It's checking the date column which is a `date` type and is called `date`, to see if the date exists in the table.

```
// Check if chosen date is available.
$s=$dbh->prepare("
    SELECT DISTINCT
        `date`
    FROM
        `report_coa_bal_hist`
    WHERE
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) = ?
");

if ($s->execute($begin)) {

    return true;

} else {

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your error. I can echo `$begin` fine.

Comment: what are you getting right now .. ?

Comment: Can we see the query that you're using for MySQL?

Comment: That's odd. I just tried to echo it again, this time closer to where the variable was set and it was echoed correctly. Sorry, something below it in the code must have been breaking it. However, next issue is why my query isn't working! I'll update the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime` creates date in unix timestamp

you have to directly use this variable without doing `strtotime` on it

```
$begin = strtotime($beginObj);
```

**Edit**

Use this query with `` ` `` around `date`

```
$s=$dbh->prepare("
SELECT DISTINCT
    `date`
FROM
    `report_coa_bal_hist`
WHERE
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) = ?");

if ($s->execute($begin)) {

    return true;

} else {

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Apologies, I've updated my question. I did try passing `$beginObj` but still got the same error. Now suspecting the error in my query.

Comment: Many thanks everyone. The problem came down to the back ticks.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code should work fine ... but alternatively you can try this

```
$datepicker_begin = "01/07/2013";
$begin = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $datepicker_begin);
echo $begin = $begin->getTimestamp();;  // becomes Unix Timestamp
```

Have a look http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Comment: Apologies, I've updated my question. Thanks for the link though. I wasn't aware of getTimestamp().

Answer (score 0):

Try FROM_UNIXTIME:

```
$datepicker_begin = "01/07/2013";
$begin = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $datepicker_begin);
$beginObj = $begin->format('Y-m-d');
$begin = strtotime($beginObj);  // becomes Unix Timestamp
$sql = "INSERT INTO test(ID, time) VALUES(NULL, FROM_UNIXTIME('$begin'));";
mysql_query($sql);
```